# Receive a web request with IFTTT

Tags: python, python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit, ifttt

I am currently using **IFTTT** to create some automated software with **Amazon Echo** (Alexa). I want to use the IFTTT's Maker channel to do so.

Here's what I want the end result to be:

1. Command Amazon Echo (Alexa) to run a program.
2. Run a Python program on my computer.

I have had success in using the Trigger function of the Maker channel using a JSON request. However, there seems to be little documentation on the Action function, where IFTTT can make a web request to a URL. I have heard that webhooks may be needed to use this, again I am not sure where to get started with this.

The image below is what the Action function asks for. I know I'll need a server on my local machine or a program reading any requests sent to a public website.

[image: The action service on IFTTT's Maker Channel]

If there are any libraries that would make this much easier, I would happily take recommendations, as this has been on my mind for a while..
Thank you!

Comment: Once you read [ask] and [mcve], you may realise that SO isn't the correct venue for these kind of questions. Maybe try https://www.quora.com/search?q=python ?

Comment: If MQTT is an acceptable medium for you, I've answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43297435/3585071 -  Basically IFTTT recipe will be like "IF <ALEXA> THEN <ADAFRUIT>" and then implement a subscriber on the target computer, which can then invoke the python script.